# Instructing web browser to switch tabs and go to URL, from external app

Tags: c#, browser, browser-extension

I wrote a C# Winforms launcher app that used to be able to interact with a browser extension that I also wrote. The launcher, which connected to the browser extension via socket, allowed the user to specify a URL, which it would send to the extension. The extension would check for an existing (already-open) browser tab with the same domain as the desired URL and switch to that tab before following the URL, instead of opening a new tab. The goal was to “recycle” already-open tabs so that the user can open the same URL over and over from the launcher without cluttering the browser with tabs that usually go to the exact same URL.

At the time, I implemented this using Firefox, but then FF started preventing such communication. My question is whether Firefox, Chrome, or Edge now allow such a solution and, if so, how might one implement it. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.